# Magento - Backend login, please wait message (loading_mask_loader) don't disappear

Tags: magento, backend, dashboard

after the last updates in our dev-system with the actual magento 1.9.3.9 a login at the backend shows the "please wait" message endless at the dashboard.

During that, you can't select and do anything (only if you hard remove the layers with browser debugging tool - loading_mask_loader is the p-layer) but i don't know how to end it?

Are there any statistic function be activated?
At the Browser dev-bar there is no activity of ajax oder other after-loading things.

can you help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Failure found!

Actualy we add CSP (Content Security Policy) options in addition to the outdated X-Frame-Options (SAMEORIGIN) used in version 1.9.x and there was some blocking entries.

Problem solved!